# How to deploy a website to internet.(ASP.NET and SQL Server )

Tags: asp.net

I am new to the web development.I have built my website in visual studio 2008 using Sql server 2008 as backend.Now I want to know the whole process of deploying the website in 
some web domains and as well as my database to some database domain.I didn't purchase any 
domain till now.I want to know about web hosting as well.

Please help me.I have googled but did not find anything which give me complete idea about this.Please refer me some documents which i can go through or something else. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database: 
For deploying your SQL Server DB, check out the Database Publishing Wizard in VS2008
You can view the steps for the same in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907585.aspx)

ASP.net Website: 
MSDN articles for deploying an ASP.net website project can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377y0s6t.aspx)